# What is the difference between trapping and handling an exception?

Tags: python, exception

I'm looking into exception handling in python and a blog post I read differentiated between trapping and handling an exception. Can someone explain the core difference between these two, both in python specifically and the overall conceptual difference? A google search for 'exception trapping handling' isn't super-useful.

Comment: This feels like imprecise language use to me. Do you have a link to the blog?

Comment: -1: No quote or link.  Really hard to guess what the blogger had in mind.

Comment: Let me add to what others have commented, `Trapping` is not a term  we use in Python world - correct me if I'm wrong. And that's the reason why they're asking for a blog post or link.

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/408937-basic-exception-handling-idiom-using-decorators/

The line:  " This adds "real" exception handling to the recipe instead of just exception "trapping". If you want to handle an exception, pass its handler to the decorator in a second tuple argument in the same order as the exceptions."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that "trapping" and "catching" an exception are the same thing: you have to trap/catch it to be able to handle it, but the act of trapping it is not the same as handling it.

`Trapping-but-not-handling = supressing`, in other words. Handling implies that you actually do something with the information at your disposal: log it, throw it to the next level, perform some action if the exception is not entirely unexpected etc.etc.

Or to put it another way, trapping an exception means that you have a code construct into which exception-al circumstances will flow, and where you can choose to handle the information that you find there.

Comment: OK this is what I thought, just wanted to be sure there wasn't any additional concept I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a conceptual difference, I'd define **Trapping** as adding code to limit the impact of an error extending to other parts of the code or being displayed by the OS to the user.

**Handling** an error would be doing something appropriate in response to the error.

From a pseudo-code stance:

```
try
  // Something which may cause an error - this is trapped by wrapping in a try/catch
catch
  //  doing something appropriate in response to the error occurring - handle it
finally
```